TransientObjectException during commit when adding entity to an uninitialized lazy collection in Hibernate
Assume, we have two simple entities Parent and Child like the following:
@Entity
public class Parent extends BaseEntity {
    private String content;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Child extends BaseEntity {
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    private int value;
}

BaseEntity just handles ID management and contains nothing special.
Essentially, we have a Parent entity that contains a list of Child entities. This relationship is lazy, all operations are cascaded, Child orphans are removed when no longer referenced.
Now we retrieve a parent and add a new child to it like the following:
@Transactional
public void run() {
        var p1 =  entityManager.find(Parent.class, 1L);

        var newChild = Child.builder()
                .value(999)
                .parent(p1)
                .build();
        p1.getChilds().add(newChild);

        entityManager.merge(p1);
}

This runs fine and the created newChild is added when the transaction commits.
But if we access the childs-collection of the parent and force Hibernate to populate the collection like in the following size()-call:
@Transactional
public void run() {
        var p1 =  entityManager.find(Parent.class, 1L);

        var newChild = Child.builder()
                .value(999)
                .parent(p1)
                .build();
        p1.getChilds().add(newChild);

        p1.getChilds().size();

        entityManager.merge(p1);
}

an Exception is thrown:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: de.lmis.lazycollection.model.Child.
The problem vanishes when

getChilds().size() is called before adding the newChild
orphanRemoval is turned off.

To me this looks rather strange and I cannot see a meaningful explanation for this behaviour. For me lazy collections included the promise that the required data is fetched when needed and the user does not have to deal with the question if and when exactly this happens. If there is no other explanation I always have to ensure that the collection is properly populated before adding someting to it.
Where am I misleaded?
Many thanks for all hints,
Dominik

I think you are getting this error due to below reason.
Whenever you call the get() method on the childs variable, it is going to be initialized through a proxy class PersistentList. Persistent List can contain only the active session objects.
In the first case, you are doing a get() after adding a transiet object to the proxy class, and proxy is going to have a problem when it tries to sync it with DB.
In the second case, You have already initialized the childs variable with the actual list by doing a size() call so it is not complaining.
